# HTML textarea doesn't update while typing in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

On a page with the following code, the textarea doesn't update with text that I type, until I click off of it. Why?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #canvas {
      float: left;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.translate(0, 0);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width=439></canvas>
  <textarea></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

I've discovered that the textarea will update properly if I do any one of the following:

- Change the width of the canvas to 438 or less
- Remove `ctx.translate(0,0);`
- Remove `float: left;`

This only happens in Chrome, I can't reproduce in Firefox.
I'm running Chrome 39.0.2171.95 and Firefox 34.0.5

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: @suchit I want to achieve having my textarea behave normally..

Comment: I had an issue with the same symptom but without a canvas on the page. Fortunately the fix worked the same. I'm still really curious about the actual cause…

Answer (score 3):

That is really odd behavior.  You can fix it by adding relative positioning to the textarea:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #canvas {
      float: left;
    }
    textarea {
      position: relative;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.translate(0, 0);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width=439></canvas>
  <textarea></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I wonder the same thing.  My original thought was that the canvas was somehow covering the textarea, so I added a z-index to the textarea.  Z-index works on positioned elements only, so I gave it relative positioning.  That fixed the problem, but on a lark I decided to remove z-index.  Amazingly, it still worked.  Crazy.